# Getting tables names from SQL statement by Regular Expression

Tags: regex, plsql

I am trying to get all table names mention in the PL/SQL statement by below regular expression. It work some extend and giving me table names. But problem in below scenarios.

```
(?<=from|join)\s+(\w+)(,\s*(\w+))?(?:(\s*\w+,\s*(\w+))+)? 


SELECT DISTINCT *
         FROM  table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3,table4 t4
WHERE t3.signature_id IS NULL
```

It only giving me table1 and table4 others are not getting by the regular expression. I think problem in `(,\s*(\w+))` not recursively look and match those table statement. My problem is how to get all names of table1, table2, table3 and table4?

Comment: This cannot be done using 1 iteration as the select query can have subqueries.

Comment: I think you can't do this with a regular expression : you need to write a proper parser guided by the sql syntax: with your approach you can be fooled by text that is contained in a comment.  And you can't distinguish proper tables from named subqueries defined by the "with" clause.  I already have been there and I wrote my own parser

Comment: Let's assume their no sub queries in select statement